# Sending notification toDatabase Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send notification to database but having some trouble. In my notifications table, DATA row is  null `{"estate":null}`. it should retrieve title and body though.

my controller is:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Notifications\NewEstateNotification;
use App\Estate;
use App\User;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function newEstate()
{
    $estate = new Estate;
    $estate->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $estate->title   = 'Laravel Notification';
    $estate->body    = 'This is the new Estate';
    $estate->save;
    $user = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)->get();

    if (\Notification::send($user, new NewEstateNotification(Estate::latest('id')->first())))
    {
        return back();
    }

}
```

NewEstateNotification class:

```
use Queueable;
protected $estate;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($estate)
{
    $this->estate = $estate;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}




public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [

        'estate' => $this->estate,

    ];
}
```

Any idea where am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your NewEstateNotification  class

Comment: I updated the question with NewEstateNotification class codes. @JigneshJoisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to used like that

```
public function newEstate()
{
    $estate = new Estate();
    $estate->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $estate->title   = 'Laravel Notification';
    $estate->body    = 'This is the new Estate';
    $estate->save();
    $users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)->get();

    //used like that 
    foreach($users as $user) {
       $user->notify(new NewEstateNotification($estate));
    } 

   return back();    
}
```

> in  NewEstateNotification add toArray() method

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'estate' => $this->estate->toArray(),
    ];
}
```

> it's also working fine if you want to used

`\Notification::send($user, new NewEstateNotification($estate))`

Comment: okay I tried this and i can send the data to DB but with foreach I sent it too many times and browser crushed :) I did not change the NewEstateNotification class the problem is in controller foreach part.

Comment: @Snickers used Notification class to send notification otherwise create new job and add them code so laravel send notifcation behind the sense (there is no load and no browser crushed)

Comment: okay I solved the problem mate. in the old code I used `$estate->save` but it's actually must be `$estate->save()` but really thankful for the help.